# Setting javax.xml.ws.Service from JDK, instead of javaee-api with maven

Tags: maven, jax-ws, classpath, classloader, ejb-3.0

I'm facing with this problem:

```
The method getPort(QName, Class<T>) in the type Service is not applicable for the arguments (QName, Class<AcessoDadosGeolocalizacao>, WebServiceFeature[])
```

I used `wsimport` to generate my clients, but now my maven application is using the class  **javax.xml.ws.Service** from

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javaee</groupId>
   <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
   <version>5</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

How can I use the **javax.xml.ws.Service** from the **JDK 6**?

Comment: Did you used the jaxws:wsimport goal or just the wsimport process from JDK?

Comment: Just the wsimport from jdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the webservices-api to my pom.xml and the problem is gone.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1-b14</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am adding this entry(webservices-api) ;it is giving run time error while accessing JAXB-API.I found that the JDK6 should be the first in the order of classpath and then maven library.I moved up the JDK6  above the Maven library.Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with Eclipse and a Dynamic Web Application. Its not Maven related however googling for that error gets you all of about 7 results in Google as of today's date with about three or more of them being relisting at other websites of the same stack exchange question - so I thought in case others had a similar issue I'd add what helped me.  The WAR was set to use JBoss AS5, the VM was set to use Java 6.  Because its eclipse and I had already consumed the web service - the error was not occurring on import as the stubs had already been created.  I ensured the Java facet was set to use 1.6 (it had been 1.5), I cleaned and built but the error persisted.  I then noticed I had a reference on my build path to Java EE 1.5.  I removed this, cleaned and built and the error went away.

Hope this helps anyone else faced with the same issue!